# Can Living Gloves combined with Remove Curse be used to gain access to multiple artisan tool skills?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, curses

[Living Gloves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/living-gloves) (p278 ERftLW) Says:

> While attuned to these gloves, you gain one of the following proficiencies (your choice when you attune to the gloves):
>
> - Sleight of Hand
> - Thieves' tools
> - One kind of artisan's tools of your choice
> - One kind of musical instrument of your choice
>
> ***Symbiotic Nature.*** The gloves can't be removed from you while you're attuned to them, and **you can't voluntarily end your attunement to them.** If you're targeted by a spell that ends a curse, your attunement to the gloves ends, and they can be removed.

Can [*remove curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse) (p271 PHB) be used to end the curse, then you can put the gloves back on to attune once again and choose a different proficiency?

Comment: Related: [Can a person attuned to Living Gloves cast Remove Curse on themselves to remove them?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171709/can-a-person-attuned-to-living-gloves-cast-remove-curse-on-themselves-to-remove?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes, you can un-attune with *remove curse*, but you lose the proficiencies you had from the gloves:

> **While attuned to these gloves**, you gain one of the following proficiencies

So you can un-attune, re-attune and choose a different proficiency, but you cannot benefit from multiple artisan tool proficiencies *at the same time* in this way.

This *does* allow you to more or less change your artisan tool proficiency with relative ease, the only consumed resources are spell slots and time to attune.

Comment: It could be argued that your character shouldn't be allowed to voluntarily go along with this scheme, and should attempt to prevent the Remove Curse from being cast. They certainly wouldn't ask their freindly Cleric to do so, even with the intent to put them back on for a different proficiency. Edit: I suppose it comes down to whether you interpret curses as making the wearer UNABLE or UNWILLING to do so.

Comment: If it could be argued, could you leave an answer making that argument? I'm not seeing it. Why can you say they "certainly" wouldn't ask the gloves to be removed?

Comment: @Maaark Feel free to post an answer to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171709/can-a-person-attuned-to-living-gloves-cast-remove-curse-on-themselves-to-remove).

Comment: @Maaark the description of living gloves [here](https://www.dndbeyond.com/search?q=living%20gloves) suggests that the wearer is unable to do so: "to attune to them, you must wear them for the entire attunement period, during which the gloves
bond with your skin."

Comment: @Maaark Unless the specific curse includes verbiage to the effect of "the character will actively work to prevent the curse from being lifted", then I don't think curses prevent the character from trying to have a curse removed.  I think the alignment changing items in previous editions were worded to that extent, and I think some artifacts also, but most did not work to prevent a Remove Curse from being sought or cast.

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: Some of them do say something like "you are unwilling to part with the [item], keeping it within reach at all times" - but yeah, I've never seen one that specifies that you'll never allow anyone to cast *remove curse* on it (though narratively, you might have no reason to want to believe that it's cursed).