# Can a person attuned to Living Gloves cast Remove Curse on themselves to remove them?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, curses, attunement

The [living gloves](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/living-gloves) (E:RftLW, pg. 278) have the feature **Symbiotic Nature**:

> The gloves can’t be removed from you while you’re attuned to them, and **you can’t voluntarily end your attunement to them**. If you’re targeted by a spell that ends a curse, your attunement to the gloves ends, and they can be removed.

If I am attuned to the living gloves and know the spell [*remove curse*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/remove-curse), would casting *remove curse* on myself count as voluntarily ending my attunement to them?

This is a follow up to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/171664/can-living-gloves-combined-with-remove-curse-be-used-to-gain-access-to-multiple), wherein a process for achieving ready access to all artisan tool proficiencies is described using *remove curse* to unattune to the living gloves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## They can, it doesn't count as voluntarily ending your attunement.

You need to read the sentence within context. The next phrase says

> If you’re targeted by a spell that ends a curse, your attunement to the gloves ends, and they can be removed.

So what the sentence you emphasized means is that, unlike other magical items, where you can end attunement at will without spending anything, the Living Gloves are different. They instead require something that breaks a curse, regardless if it's you casting the spell or not.